# I want to send two parameters on one ajax request 

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code and i want send two value 
as you see i have ledit in data i want to send ledit2 with ledit

```
$('.ledit').click(function() {
    var ledit = $(this).attr("id");
    var ledit2 = $('.valu').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'edit.php',
        data: 'ledit=' + ledit,
        // here i want send ledit2
        success: function(data) {
            $('.edito').html('dddddddddd');
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: please clarify - do you want to send two parameters in one call, or two actual calls?

Answer (score 7):

You can set `data` property as an object:

```
$('.ledit').click(function() {
    var ledit = $(this).attr("id");
    var ledit2 = $('.valu').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'edit.php',
        data: {
            ledit : ledit,
            ledit2 : ledit2
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.edito').html('dddddddddd');
        }
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

why two calls? Just do a single ajax call passing both the values

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'edit.php',
        data: 'ledit=' + ledit + "&ledit2=" + ledit2,
        ...
});
```

anyway unless you encode your values (e.g. with `encodeURIComponent`) it's better to use an object, as suggested by @VisioN

Comment: so what happens to your code when the user puts an illegal character in `.valu` ?

Comment: of course the object is a better choice in that case: my answer was to point out that making an ajax call for every value is awful.

Comment: and how i resbose it in php file like this $id  =  $_GET['ledit'];
$val = $_GET['ledit2'];

Comment: @ChopperMio In PHP you can retrieve the values exactly as you have written.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an object literal for the `data` parameter:

```
data: { ledit: ledit, ledit2: ledit2 }
```

Or you can just use the `&` operator in the URL:

```
data: 'ledit=' + ledit + '&ledit2=' + ledit2
```

Comment: no, please, don't use concatenation and `&`.  Let jQuery do its job and correctly escape the parameters for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do it like this?

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'edit.php',
        data: '{ "ledit":' + ledit + ', "ledit2":' + ledit2 + '}',
        success: function(data) {
            $('.edito').html('dddddddddd');
        }
    });
```

Or much better:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'edit.php',
        data: JSON.stringify({ ledit: ledit, ledit2: ledit2}),
        success: function(data) {
            $('.edito').html('dddddddddd');
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you stringify it there, doesn't it get serialized twice? How is that effective?